Token icon not showing up in Phantom wallet
I'm part of the team for a pump.fun launched token ($WIFE / Wifejak), and we've had some complaints that our token icon is not always showing up next to balances on Phantom Wallet. Can anyone suggest a reason why this might be, and how to fix?
WIFE solscan - https://solscan.io/token/4y3oUrsJfSp431R3wJrWiaLxRPsnYtpkVJmoV2bYpBiy
